# Size limit in MATLAB MEX-files

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-deployment

I'm new to Matlab mex. I'm trying to write a mex function which in turn will take the structure data from a .cpp file and use it in Matlab.

I came to know that plhs and prhs are the pointers to an array which hold the output data and input data respectively, each element of type mxArray.

Since structure size can be large, Is there any maximum size limit for the plhs and prhs array to hold the data ? If so, What are the alternate ways?

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Never mind, I posted the same here: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/501403-limit-in-mex-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've researched the size of arrays that can be handled depends on the API you compile your mex files with. You can choose the API by adding the corresponding flag in your compiling instruction. The details are in the [matlab documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) under "api-release specific API".

There are 4 options avaliable: `-R2017b (default)` `-R2018a` `-largeArrayDims` and `-compatibleArrayDims`.

In term of array size `-R2017b (default)` `-R2018a`  and `-largeArrayDims` use the Large-array-handling API which according to the  [matlab mex documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) can handle arrays over 2<sup>31</sup>-1 and, according to the [API documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-large-mxarrays.html) should be able to handle arrays up to 2<sup>48</sup>-1 elements and sparse arrays up to 2<sup>48</sup>-2.

Only the last option, `-compatibleArrayDims` won't handle arrays above 2<sup>31</sup>-1

Apart from array size those options will change the way a few data types are handled, noticeably complex types and graphics object.

So in short:

- `-R2017b (default)` : 2<sup>48</sup>-1 elements per array
- `-R2018a` : 2<sup>48</sup>-1 elements per array
- `-largeArrayDims` : 2<sup>48</sup>-1 elements per array
- `-compatibleArrayDims` 2<sup>31</sup>-1 elements per array

Finally if you want to handle larger object the solution I see would be to write your results in files (.txt or .csv for example) in the c-part of your code and read them back in the matlab part in whole or in chunks.